# compare two datagridview tables by specific column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Good day!
I need to compare two DataGridView tables on a specific column and display the matches in `datagridview3` and the discrepancies in `datagridview4`.
So far, that's all I have done. I can display in the message:
Tell me how to change the code.

```
For Each rw1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    For Each rw2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
        If rw1.Cells(3).Value = rw2.Cells(3).Value Then
            If rw1.Cells(3).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                MsgBox(rw1.Cells(3).Value & "  in dgv2")
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

**data in table 1:**

| Surname | Name | address | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Surname1 | Name1 | Adress1 | 14526 |
| Surname2 | Name2 | Adress2 | 75856 |
| Surname3 | Name3 | Adress3 | 36514 |
| Surname4 | Name4 | Adress4 | 78425 |
| Surname5 | Name5 | Adress5 | 36178 |
| Surname6 | Name6 | Adress6 | 98317 |

**data in table 2:**

| Surname | Name | address | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Surname3 | Name3 | Adress3 | 36514 |
| Surname5 | Name5 | Adress5 | 36178 |
| Surname2 | Name2 | Adress2 | 75856 |
| Surname6 | Name6 | Adress6 | 98317 |

I need to display matches by list (column with index 3) in `datagridview3` and divergences by list in `datagridview4`.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Based on your comment wanting a Universal solution - DataTables have a [Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columns?view=netframework-4.8) Propert Collection that you can use in a `For Each` loop just like [Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Can I have a code example, please, specifically for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq) to do the heavy lifting of finding matching and non-matching entries, it then befores a matter of looping through the cells and setting the values in the target DataGridViews

```
Dim dgv1Rows As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).ToList()
Dim dgv2Rows As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = DataGridView2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).ToList()

Dim matchingItems = dgv1Rows.Where(Function(x)
                                        Return dgv2Rows.Any(Function(y) x.Cells(3).Value = y.Cells(3).Value)
                                    End Function)

Dim notMatchingItems = dgv1Rows.Where(Function(x)
                                            Return Not dgv2Rows.Any(Function(y) x.Cells(3).Value = y.Cells(3).Value)
                                        End Function)

For Each rw1 As DataGridViewRow In matchingItems
    Dim addedRowId As Integer = dgvMatching.Rows.Add()
    Dim targetRow As DataGridViewRow = dgvMatching.Rows(addedRowId)
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In rw1.Cells
        targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
    Next
Next

For Each rw1 As DataGridViewRow In notMatchingItems
    Dim addedRowId As Integer = dgvNotMatching.Rows.Add()
    Dim targetRow As DataGridViewRow = dgvNotMatching.Rows(addedRowId)
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In rw1.Cells
        targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
    Next
Next
```

This simply loops through all the cells in the DataGridViewRow setting the value in the appropriate target (dgvMatching or dgvNotMatching) DataGridViewRow. It will work for any number of cells/columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follow instead of your MsgBox

```
    Dim row As String() = New String() {rw1.Cells(0).Value, rw1.Cells(1).Value, rw1.Cells(2).Value, rw1.Cells(3).Value}
    DataGridView3.Rows.Add(row)
```

then follow the same idea to make the divergeances in **DataGridView4** after the `else`

Comment: YES, I tried like this, but I need a universal solution. Since the number of columns may vary